# Why does Folium Time slider not work in IE11?

Tags: time-series, geojson, folium

I am using Folium for rendering Time series data using the following code snippet:

```py
TimestampedGeoJson(
        {'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'features': features}
        , period='P1D'
        , add_last_point=False
        , auto_play=True
        , loop=True
        , max_speed=1
        , loop_button=True
        , date_options='YYYY-MM-DD'
        , time_slider_drag_update=True
        
    ).add_to(VMap)
```

This works beautifully on all browsers except IE11. For some reason, the time slider in IE11 displays an error - *Time not available* The slider is rendered perfectly in other browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Edge etc.
I am forced to save the map and open with some other browser. Is there a workaround for this compatibility issue? How can timesliders be rendered correctly in ieXX ? Been looking at various posts for this.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this one out! The issue is that the Time slider shows dates as YYYY-MM-DD. When converting dates to string, the standard date string str(value.Date) adds 00:00 for hours mins etc. Whilst a lot of browsers ignore this, IE11 requires it as a 10 character string YYYY-MM-DD. I took care of this whilst building the features array for GeoJason as follows:

```
# Build features array for use with GeoJson
features = []
for idx, value in Globalcases_df.iterrows():
    times = str(value.Date)
    times = times[:10]      #YYYY-MM-DD
    feature = {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
                'type':'Point', 
                'coordinates':[value.Long,value.Lat]  #GeoJson Coordinates are Longitude, Latitude, Altitude!
            },
            'properties': {
                'time': times,
                'icon': 'circle',
                'iconstyle':{
                    'fillOpacity': 0.8,
                    'color': 'red',
                    'stroke': 'true',
                    'radius': 3,
                   
                }
            }
        }
    features.append(feature)
```